# Parsing an XML file with a time delay in Javascript/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I'm making an online scoreboard with a replay feature. Every second of a game for the scoreboard is stored in a record in a database in XML format so that it can be parsed. The user should be able to choose a game to replay and JS will replay the game on a second-by-second basis.

As each game lasts ~15 minutes with a lot of events, a game will have around ~3mb of data attached to it. I figure the best way to do this would be to create a temporary XML file based on the game data for a JS file to preload to the browser to parse and display.

So, would this be the best method, and if not what would be?

Note: It's being made in PHP.

Comment: I'm not liking the sound of `stored in a record in a database in XML format` - you should store the *data* in the database, not the XML, and you generate XML based on that data on request. Or is that just me...?

Comment: I see your point, will see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending 3 MB of data and parsing it on the client can take quite some time. To make the sure the data takes less space and is parseable faster, you could use JSON instead of XML.

Also, do you need the whole file at once? If not, I'd suggest an AJAX "loader" routine that does the following:

1. Read x minutes worth of game data
2. Parse it and add it to the data pool
3. Request the x minutes, jumping to 2 when the data has loaded.

The ideal value for x is a question of network speed vs replay speed. Each request would add some HTTP header and TCP overhead, so test it with different network conditions.

Comment: That sounds good. I've started it based on basic php > xml > js, but will have a go with your method when I get round to optimising